# Printing the content of an Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, printing, echo

The following PHP code attempts to print an array. However, the output simply states 'Array' rather than the content of the Array. If anyone could tell me out to print the contents instead I would be very grateful.

```
<?php 


 $greetings1 = array(
    'a' => 'hello',
    'b' => 'hi',
);
$greetings2 = array(
    'c' => 'hey',
    'd' => 'greetings',
);

$greetings = array_merge($greetings1, $greetings2);

echo $greetings;

?>
```

Thankyou

Andrew

Comment: use `print_r($array)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
print_r($greetings);
```

instead of

```
echo $greetings;//Echo is used to display string.
```

For more check the documenation

1. [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)
2. [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

Comment: Great thankyou that helps, now I have: 

Array ( [a] => hello [b] => hi [c] => hey [d] => greetings )

I would prefer to have hello, hi, hey, greetings as the output

Comment: You need to learn more about looping statements to iterate through an array.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($greetings); 
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

To print array use :

1. `print_r` :

   `echo "<pre>"; 
   print_r($greetings);
   echo "</pre>";`

   Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php
2. `var_dump` :

   `echo "<pre>"; 
   var_dump($greetings);
   echo "</pre>";`

   Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php
3. Use `foreach` and `echo` :

   `foreach ($greetings as $key=>$val)
   {
     echo "You Key : ".$key." And Your value : ".$val;
   }`

   Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways:

`print_r($greetings);`
Prints in a human-readable way

`var_export($greetings);`
Prints it such that you can use it within PHP source.

`var_dump($greetings);`
Prints very detailed information (including data types of members - useful if your array contains boolean or null values

Answer (score 1):

You can not print `array` variable using `echo` statement.

Use can use `print_r()` to print array elements.

e.g,

```
print_r($greetings);
```

OR

```
var_dump($greetings);
```